# How to JavaDoc an Action Listener

Tags: java, comments, javadoc

I have an ActionListener:

```
private ActionListener someAction = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

How would I go about commenting this for a JavaDoc. I think I have three options:

- Add my comment above `private ActionListener...`
- Add my comment above `@Override`
- Add my comment above `public void actionPerformed...`

Where would it be best to add my JavaDoc comment?

Comment: To add Javadoc on an ActionListener, you'd have to have it as a member of a class. You wouldn't be able to add Javadoc inside a method. Though, as the duplicate says, you'd better add comments on your encapsulating method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not Document Anonymous Inner Classes because the JavaDoc Tool ignore its.

> The Javadoc tool does not directly document anonymous classes -- that
>   is, **their declarations and doc comments are ignored.**
>   If you want to document an anonymous class, the **proper way to do so is**
>   **in a doc comment of its outer class**, or another closely associated
>   class.

From [Java Docs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#anonymous)